# Python 3 Web Scrape & Beautiful Soup - Hidden info

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have just started to use Python 3 & Beautiful soup and have obtained most of the visible information that I can see on the page using find() or findAll().

One of the pages that I have looked at dynamically loads an item code (productPLU) that is hidden on the page that you see normally, but is contained within the HTML code  as per below:-

div class="product ng-scope" ng-controller="ProductListItemController" ng-init="productPLU = '384353'"

Is it possible to scrape the productPLU information?
If so, what syntax would I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you see this tag in parsed html?

Comment: Hi, yes. I parsed the page into soup and re-checked. I can clearly see the code. The product code for each wrapper is different for each product. The product code is simply not displayed on the standard web page.